# How can i reset the httpd.conf file

Tags: apache, wampserver

Does anyone know how I can find the httpd.conf file because I may have accidentally changed some things inside and i can't `Ctrl+z` because I opened it in notepad file instead of notepad++. i would reinstall the whole wampserver but I have tons of data and files to take the risk. I just need the original file of httpd.conf of Apache 2.4.9. I couldn't find it online.

Comment: there isn't really an "official" httpd.conf. there's only the httpd.conf provided by whoever packaged your particular copy of apache. if you want the wampserver one, then extract it from the installer.

Comment: @MarcB how can i do that, extracting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a program such as 7-zip to extract all the files from the wamp installer. Go find the httpd.conf file and copy it over. Also you could just install it temporarily on another windows computer to retrieve the file.
It's good practice to always make a backup of conf files before modifying them, they are specific to your release of apache and the environment it's meant to be used in.

Comment: Thanks, I just ran the installer and chose a different location to install the files, and found the file

Comment: That will have installed WAMPServer into the new location. The Apache and MYSQL Services will now be running from the new location